# Opensource push based API for RSS feed

Tags: python, parsing, rss

I have checked various Python rss feed parser and it works well. I am able to parse the rss feed result using pulling mechanism.

```
    data_et = feedparser.parse('http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/Markets/markets/rssfeeds/1977021501.cms')
    for value in data_et['entries']:
        print value['link']
```

Is there any opensource API with push based mechanism, so rather then I make request to server for updated data, I get notification that new updates are available.

P.S. I dont want mail based or Desktop application based notification. I want it to happen programatically using python

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [PubSubHubbub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) open protocol which will use a webhook pattern to send you notification when a feed has been updated. Also check [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) which does the same but for *any* feed.